# How to find an LP for the robust counterpart of the uncertain LP problem

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, polyhedra

I am trying to answer the following problem but with no success:

Let $c\in \mathbb{R}^n, b\in \mathbb{R}^m, \bar{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $\Delta\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}_+$ be given.
Additionally, let $B = \{A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n} : |A_{ij} - \bar{A}_{ij} | \leq \Delta_{ij} \; \forall i,j \}$.
We call a vector $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ a robust feasible solution to the uncertain problem if $Ax \leq b$ for all $A\in B$.
Write an explicit LP that minimizes $c^T x$ over all robust feasible solutions, and whose number of variables and constraints is polynomial in $m, n$.

I'm not even sure what a good start to the problem would be.
If anyone could suggest a path to solve this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have any conditions on $x$? Is it nonnegative?

Comment: No conditions on $x$ other than that it must be a robust feasible solution as defined above

Answer (score 2):

Study single rows of the constraints, and write each element as $\bar a_{ij} + \Delta_{ij}z_{ij}$ where $|z_{ij}|\leq 1$, leading to $\sum_j a_{ij}x_j + \sum_j \Delta_{ij}z_{ij}x_j \leq b_i$. Can you see what the worst-case $z$ is and take it from there?

Comment: I don't see what the worst $z_{ij}$ would be because it is unknown whether $x\geq 0$ or $x\leq 0$. If it were true that we always have $x\geq 0$ or $x\leq 0$ then I could see what the worst case $z_{ij}$ would be, but without those conditions I don't see. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: So depending on the sign of $\Delta_{ij}x_j$, what would worst-case $z_{ij}$ be and what would that tell you about the product $\Delta_{ij}z_{ij}x_j$

Comment: Ah I think I see. So we need to have two constraints for every row. So our LP will be:
\begin{align*}
    &\min  \;\;  c^T x\\
    \text{subject to } & \sum_j a_{ij} x_j - \sum_j \Delta_{ij} x_j \leq b_i  \hspace{0.5cm} \forall j=1, \dots, m\\
                                  & \sum_j a_{ij} x_j + \sum_j \Delta_{ij} x_j \leq b_i \hspace{0.5cm} \forall j=1, \dots, m
\end{align*} 

right?

Comment: No, what you have done now is the robust counterpart for $(\sum_j \Delta_{ij}x_{ij})z_i$. you have to introduce new variables/constraints to model that the worst-case of every single term is $|\Delta_{ij}x_{ij}|$. More generally, the model $a^Tx + c^Tz\leq 1$ with $|z|_{\infty}\leq 1$ is given by $a^Tx + |c|_1 \leq 1$

Comment: I think I understand. So the following can be our LP:
\begin{align*}
    \min & c^T x\\
    \text{subject to } & \sum\limits_j a_{ij}x_j + \sum\limits_j \Delta_{ij} u_j \leq b_i  & \forall i=1, \dots, m\\
    & x_j \leq u_j & \forall j=1, \dots, n\\
 & -x_j \leq u_j & \forall j=1, \dots, n\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Since $\Delta$ is positive, yes.